# Rewrite with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to rewrite following code with python list comprehension

```
vuln = []
for p in pkgs:
    m = get_close_matches(p, rpms)
    if m:
        vuln.append(m)

if vuln:
   print(vuln)
```

My first version is below

```
  vuln = [get_close_matches(p, rpms)
                            for p in pkgs]
  if vuln:
       print(vuln)
```

Unfortunately it produces a list of empty list if there are no matches

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
[m for m in (get_close_matches(p, rpms) for p in pkgs) if m]
```

Because you are first sending `p` into a function, and then checking that functions return has a value.

This will iterate each `m` item, and check it for a value, if it has a value, it will be given to you.

Comment: Does it just look awesome? or does it solve your problem? If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [Accept my Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/192545).

Comment: The line is a bit long. So would it be a good idea to move internal generator into separate function ?

Comment: The code I supplied is 60 characters long, Which is not long at all. If you want to refactor the generator function out - that will increase the complexity of the solution. Frankly - line length is not something you should really concern yourself over nowadays, it is no longer of any actual consequence in todays programming world, the PEP8 guide suggests not to go over 120 characters if you can help it, but that's about it. (Though, indeed, in days gone by, 80 characters was almost a required maximum)

Comment: why not use the filter? `filter(None, [get_close_matches(p, rpms) for p in pkgs])`

Comment: Check the timing, and efficiency - my method is better.